# ProcessBuilder not working outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I have a ProcessBuilder which is supposed to execute the main method of a certain class with 2 parameters. I made a small JFrame in the main method just to test whether this works.

When I run the code in Eclipse I get the JFrame, but when I export this as a JAR I don't get the JFrame...

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test
{
    public static void runTest(String arg1, String arg2)
    {

        try
        {
            String pathToJar = SelfUpdate.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path") + ";" + pathToJar, Test.class.getCanonicalName(), arg1, arg2);
            pb.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JLabel l = new JLabel("test");
        f.add(l);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
}
```

runTest gets called from a different class.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: This may, or may not be the problem, but you should not exit(0) the system as quickly as you do, it is quite possible that the timing in the eclipse version is changed slightly, and there's enough time for the processbuilder to set up the forked process. You should put in a sleep(1000), or `pb.start().waitFor();`;

Comment: @rolfl yes, `waitFor` is a good idea.

Comment: Tried both waitFor() and Thread.sleep(4000). Still nothin'.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because the execution context is wrong. For Java to find your jar file and class, it must be executed within a relative context. Make sure when you run the class, you are running within a local context of ./ to the jar file. I'm also curious as to how you execute the run method

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and continue to build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this doesnot work because you didnot add `Main-Class` to your manifest.

Try to generate your jar in the following way:

```
C:/> echo Main-Class: Test >manifest.txt
jar -cvfm sample.jar manifest.txt com/sample/*.class
```